# how to write Burmese in latex?

Tags: languages, brahmic-scripts

I'm working with a linguist who is writing a paper about Burmese. I'm trying to get his paper to work in latex. There're lots of symbols in Burmese. but I struggle to find the commands in latex to get them displayed. Can I please get some help with this. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks very much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should consider using fontspec and XeLaTeX, then you can input the characters directly.

Answer (score 7):

If you use xelatex or lualatex then you can use fonts installed on your system.
I made a sample text using google translate and firefox displayed it using a font "Mayanmar Text" which probably came with Windows, so I can access that font in xelatex as:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Myanmar Text}
\begin{document}

တစ်နှစ်သုံးဟဲလိုကမ္ဘာကြီး
\end{document}
```

which hopefully says

> one two three hello world

Answer (score 4):

For any future people looking to write in a Myanmar language (Burmese, Kayin/Karen, Mon, etc.) I'll share what I've learned so far.

Use XeLaTeX, as that is the best way to get the script to render properly. I've had trouble with LuaLaTeX; i.e. it would not render the script properly. If you're familiar with Myanmar script, it was like looking at Zawgyi-encoded text with a Unicode font, or vice-versa. Also use Padauk or Padauk book as your font with the fontspec package; if you want to have clean line breaks an Open Type font is necessary here. Encoding should be UTF-8.

With the above applied, you should be fine writing with any Unicode keyboard (Padauk is a Unicode font, unlike the commonly used Zawgyi font and keyboard for Burmese). Windows has one built in, and you can find a few others on the web. Sample code below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "my"  %Myanmar line and character breaks
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 2.5pt
%under 2pt and I still was getting text going past the margins.
\setmainfont[Script=Myanmar]{Padauk Book}
\begin{document}
မြန်မာလိုရေး‌‌နေပါသည်
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SE. Would you mind clarifying what exact issues you ran into with LuaLaTeX? Thanks.

Comment: For use with LuaLaTeX, you’ll be interested in HarfTeX (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/493180).

Comment: Another common technique for this is to declare `\newfontfamily\myanmarfont{Paduak Book}[Script=Myanmar]` followed by `\DeclareTextFontCommand\textmyanmar{\myanmarfont}`.  This lets you write individual words or passages in the language.

Comment: Is using the ```\newfontfamily``` and ```\DeclareTextFontCommand``` recommended over simply using ```{\fontspec{Padauk Book} sample text}```? If so, why? What are the advantages?