# What is "latex-dev"?

Tags: packages, latex3, latex-base, bugtracking

**no answer needed, I'm adding the question as reference**

The package/update manager of my  TeX-system installed in the last weeks a number of packages called `latex-XX-dev`, and CTAN too shows a number of such packages: `latex-base-dev`, `latex-doc-dev`, `latex-graphics-dev`, and even some executables `latex-bin-dev` and `latex-bin-dev.win32`. I saw people referring to them as `latex-dev`.

#### **What are this packages for and how can I use them?**

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: https://tug.org/tug2019/abstracts/mittelbach-dev.txt

Comment: https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2019-FMi-TUB-tb125mitt-dev-format.pdf

Comment: @HenriMenke you can write the answer if you want ;-) See also https://www.latex-project.org/news/2019/09/01/LaTeX-dev-format/

Comment: I think Frank should write an answer.

Comment: @HenriMenke Frank asked me to do it.

Comment: Will we see harftex and harflatex included in these?

Comment: @DavidPurton harflatex-dev and also luahblatex-dev are already in the texmf.cnf. You only need perhaps a renamed copy of harflatex.exe and an entry in a local fmtutil.cnf.

Comment: Should OS packagers include these -dev binaries?

Comment: Update as of October 2020: PDFLaTeX-dev and LuaLaTeX-dev are _fast_. I really enjoy using them.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Perhaps one addition to Ulrike's  answer (it is included implicitly in [link given in her answer](https://www.latex-project.org/news/2019/09/01/LaTeX-dev-format/), but worth pointing to very directly without the need to follow the link):

### Our hope is to attract additional beta-testers

We don’t expect everybody to start using the development formats to participate in testing, but we hope that people with a strong interest in a stable LaTeX environment (especially developers and maintainers of important packages) will use the new facilities and help us to ensure that future public releases of LaTeX do not (as has happened in the past) require some immediate patches because of issues that were not identified by our internal regression test suite or by other testing that we do.

Any issue identified when using the development format should preferably be logged as an issue on GitHub, following the procedure outlined in https://www.latex-project.org/bugs/ including the use of the latexbug package as described.

Our bug reporting process normally states that issues involving third-party software are out of scope as we can’t correct external packages. However, in the particular case of the development format showing an incompatibility with a third-party package, it is fine to open an issue with us (in addition, please, to informing the maintainer of that package) so that we know about the problem and can jointly work on resolving it.

Comment: I certainly did not know about this till today.  If attracting beta testers is desired, perhaps a very brief message printed at the very end of a tlmgr update is in order, something like this: "Please consider test compiling your documents with the pre-release versions of tex/latex, see <link>."

Comment: @dedded we are still learning how this is all best done (there will be an announcement on https://www.latex-project.org for example in a few days), but your suggestion is worth considering in addition for the next pre-release.

Comment: So in short, how do I compie my files using this new release, I am using TEXMAKER

Answer (score 26):

### General Answer

`latex-dev` is a pre-release of LaTeX from the development branch and made  available on CTAN.

It allows users of current TeXLive and MikTeX distributions to test their documents and code against the upcoming LaTeX release with ease.

To use it you only need to compile with a binary with the addition `-dev` attached. For all major engines/latex variants such executables have been created and added to the distribuations. For example, if you run one of

```
 pdflatex-dev file
 lualatex-dev file
 xelatex-dev file
```

you will see in the log

```
 LaTeX2e <YYYY-MM-DD> pre-release-XX
```

instead of the standard `LaTeX2e <YYYY-MM-DD> patch level X`.

The first line will also says something like this

```
This is pdfTeX, .... (preloaded format=pdflatex-dev 2022.4.10) 
                                           ^^^^^^^
```

You will also see that a number of files from the `tex/latex-dev` folder will be used:

```
   .../tex/latex-dev/base/book.cls
   .../tex/latex-dev/graphics/graphicx.sty
```

Files which are not in `tex/latex-dev` will be taken from the standard locations:

```
  .../tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
```

More information:

https://www.latex-project.org/news/2019/09/01/LaTeX-dev-format/

New dev versions and the changes they contained are announced on our website.

### Update 2021-05-06

The newest `latex-dev` announces itself as

```
LaTeX2e <2021-05-01> pre-release-2 (develop 2021-5-5 branch)
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
```

Details about the changes can be found at https://www.latex-project.org/news/2021/05/05/latex-dev-2021-2/

**Please report issues that you find with the dev-release in the latex2e github so that they can be corrected**

Main changes are

- better support for copy-and-paste from LaTeX-generated PDF documents by including glyphtounicode mappings;
- support for producing several footnote marks to one footnote with the help of the \footref command;
- additional support for package and class option lists that use key/value syntax;
- additional hooks for paragraph and commands.

### Update 2020-07-23

The newest `latex-dev` announces itself as

```
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> pre-release-7 (develop 2020-7-22 branch)
L3 programming layer <2020-07-17> xparse <2020-03-03>
```

Details about the changes can be found at https://www.latex-project.org/news/2020/07/22/latex-dev-2020-10-1b/

The main changes are

- xparse is now included in the kernel
- A general hook management system for LaTeX has been implemented.

  - Hooks and commands provided by packages like `atbegshi`, `everyshi`, `filehook`, `atveryend`, `etoolbox` are now in the kernel.
  - Commands to create new hooks have been added
  - Commands to add code to hooks and to control their order have been added

The new hooks can for example be used to add code to environments more easily (but don't try this with figure, it won't like to be boxed ...).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\AddToHook{env/quote/begin}{\begin{tcolorbox}[colframe=red]\sffamily}
\AddToHook{env/quote/end}{\end{tcolorbox}}
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
An important quote
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

The new hook system requires a number of internal changes and it does break with some packages. Problematic are packages which patch core commands like `\document`, `\enddocument`, `\begin`, and packages which use low-level commands to patch e.g. the shipout box. A number of packages with such problems have already been identified (e.g. pgf looses some shadings, xecjk redefines \document and so doesn't compile, similar with tex4ht) and we are in contact with the authors to resolve the clashes.

**Please report issues that you find with the dev-release in the latex2e github so that they can be corrected**

### Update 2020-01-21

The newest `latex-dev` announces itself as

```
LaTeX2e <2020-02-01> pre-release-3 (develop 2020-1-16 branch)
```

The main changes are extensions to the NFSS (the New Font Selection Mechanism for LaTeX):

Many modern fonts available these days offer additional font faces, e.g., small caps italics or a condensed font series, etc. To better support these fonts NFSS  was extended by incorporating ideas from the mweights, fontaxes and fontspec packages. In addition all symbols formerly provided through the textcomp package are now available out of the box and the use of \oldstylenums got improved.

The release also fixed a number of smaller bugs. A detailed description of the new features and the bug fixes can be found in a draft version of ltnews31 which you can access via texdoc ltnews31 if the pre-release is installed on your computer.

### Update 2019-11-21

The newest `latex-dev` announces itself as

```
LaTeX2e <2020-02-01> pre-release-2 (development 2019-11-21 branch)
```

The main change is that it preloads a large part of the expl3 code. This will reduce the loading time for the unicode engines when using `fontspec`, but also benefit `pdflatex` documents using xparse or expl3.

`lualatex-dev` is now based on the new `luahbtex` engine. This allows to use the harfbuzz library to shape fonts. This will improve the shaping of various scripts.

### Update 2019-09-20

The newest `latex-dev` version now contains also `latex-amsmath-dev` and `latex-tools-dev`. The format annouces itself as

```
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> pre-release-3 (development 2019-9-18 branch)
```

The main change is that a number of commands have been made robust. TeXLive user should get the packages through `autoinstall`, MiKTeX user should check with the package manager and install the packages.

### First LaTeX-dev

One example of an upcoming feature was the better UTF8-handling. With `pdflatex-dev` labels with non-ascii-chars in the name no longer error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Straße}\label{sec:straße}

\ref{sec:straße}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And how to make use of and test `latex-graphics-dev`?

Comment: @AlexG when you use a -dev executable it will use all dev files installed in your system. E.g. on my system `texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/graphics/graphicx.sty` is loaded.

Comment: @AlexG I added an edit to clarify this point.

Comment: Does this mean that from now on there is no need to load the `xparse` package?

Comment: @AndréC If you run the new format, you won't need it, with the exception of some edge cases:  the argument types g/G, l and u are not provided by the kernel code; see https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews32.pdf for details.

Comment: The "old answer" should appear at the top of this answer. Otherwise, it's unreadable. The question was "What is "latex-dev"?", so the answer should address that and explain how to use it *right away*, not only at the end.

Comment: @Atcold I moved it to the top.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: What's the status as of 2022/2023? My distribution (Arch) offers TexLive packaged as of April 2022. The -dev executables do not exist, even though manual entries do. I have an older release (2021) on a machine at work, for which the -dev executables are just links to the normal formats.The formats do not seem to exist. The `tex/latex-dev` directory exists under TEXMFDIST, but I have no clue as to how to use these files.