# Dealing with updates issues

Tags: latex3, update

I have stumbled several times after an update to the `LaTeX` core, either `2e` or `3`. Isn't there a procedure that announces to developers or maintainers of affected packages to check their compatibility against the update?
IMHO, I think that waiting for users' posts to manifest is a rather primitive procedure.

Comment: for latex2e there is now latex-dev: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506646/what-is-latex-dev.

Comment: Frank wrote a detailed article on the approach and challenges: https://www.latex-project.org/news/2019/09/01/LaTeX-dev-format/. The same ideas apply to `expl3`: there is a big test suite, but the number of use cases is so large it's not all testable.

Comment: In a sense this is a general programming problem: how do you get people to test their code against upcoming library changes. The people writing the library can't make their users test stuff ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are trying hard to identify possibly affected packages in case of changes or additions beforehand by analysing the contents of the TeX Live `texmf` tree and then informing the developers beforehand, but obviously that is a process that can't be automated and there is a high liklyhood that we overlook a case. Furthermore if changes affect code in the preamble of documents or in locally installed files not in the general distributions then there is clearly no way for us to identify that.

To improve the situation we established the concept of the `latex-dev` formats which contain an unreleased/beta version of the next LaTeX2e kernel and which can be easily used by package authors (or other interested folks) to test their documents against an upcoming release so that any issues can be identified *before* that release hits the streets. The procedure is simple and works without the need to install anything (as the beta is part of the main Tex distributions), see  https://www.latex-project.org/news/2019/09/01/LaTeX-dev-format/ for details.

**Of course, that requires that the developer test!**

Anouncements that a beta is ready for testing will be done through multiple channels, e.g. in the news feed of our [web site](https://www.latex-project.org) but also elsewhere.