# How to build the binaries pdflatex-dev and friends

Tags: packages, latex-base

pdflatex-dev and variants are helpful for catching issues before new releases, as detailed at [What is "latex-dev"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506646/what-is-latex-dev). There appear to be several bugs reported and fixed since the latest pre-release was released. It would be nice to be able to test the latest revision by building the binaries from the latest source so I can check whether a failure has already been fixed. However, I can't find information on how to do this. Specifically, how can I build the newest (unreleased) pdflatex-dev, lualatex-dev, and xelatex-dev rather than using them from [latex-bin-dev](https://ctan.org/pkg/latex-base-dev?lang=en)?

In case it matters for the steps, I'm on Ubuntu 20.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need new binaries, only a new format.

1. Clone the latex2e github https://github.com/latex3/latex2e.
2. Switch to the develop branch
3. In the main folder or in the base folder (if you want only the base files) run

   ```
   l3build install
   ```

   This will install the files in your texmfhome. You can change the location either by setting the texmfhome environment variable or by using `l3build --texmfhome some-other-location install`.
   The other location should a texmf tree searched by your texsystem before the main one.
4. Then run `fmtutil-sys --byfmt pdflatex-dev`

Comment: After I do the above (which works), is it possible to uninstall it? I would like for `pdflatex-dev` to be the same as before I installed with this approach. I tried doing `l3build uninstall` followed by `fmtutil-sys --byfmt pdflatex-dev` but the output of `pdflatex-dev` (the version lines) still give the date on which I built the Git version. Let me know if it's preferred I start a new question for this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I never tried the uninstall target before but just did it now and if worked fine for me. I can't say what failed for you, but you can always simply delete the local files in the texmfhome or where ever you install them and then rebuilt the format.

Comment: Thank you for checking that. I must have done something wrong. Just to make sure, to rebuild the format it is sufficient to run `fmtutil-sys --byfmt pdflatex-dev`, right?

Comment: yes, unless you have once built a user format (with fmtutil) which shadows the system format. Check if you have  more than one format with `kpsewhich --all -engine=pdftex pdflatex-dev.fmt`

Comment: It seems I only have one format. The command returns: `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex-dev.fmt`. Your helpful responses give me enough information to dig more on my own in case I want to pursue this puzzle of why pdflatex-dev is not restored to before. I might however just give up. In any case, thank you!