# paragraph numbering with koma-script

Tags: numbering, koma-script, paragraphs

I need to write reports that have numbered paragraphs. I have seen suggestions like [Numbering paragraphs in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129208/numbering-paragraphs-in-latex) but these require inserting `\paragraph` or similar each paragraph which I find tedious.
With the extensive formatting options in koma-script (I use this package as my routine) I would have thought I could do something to do this automagically. I have looked in the manual but it seems that redeclaresectioncommand does not extend down to paragraphs.
Does anyone have a method to produce

## section 1

1. blah blah blah
2. blah blah

### subsection 1

3. blah blah

## section 2

4. blah blah

If the numbering resets within each section or subsection that is ok but not preferred.

thanks

Comment: With a current LaTeX you can use the new para hooks to insert such numbers. The main problem is that "paragraphs" are in many places where you don't want such a number, e.g. in the header and footer and you will have to  disable them there. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/595922/2388

Comment: Take a look at scrjura. No promises, but I seem to recall it supports numbered paragraphs.

Comment: scrjura numbers paragraphs if more than 1 in a section, but resets the numbering in each section.

Answer (score 1):

Only a very clumsy solution, but maybe someone with a better knowledge can shorten this:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrjura}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{remreset}


\renewcommand*{\Clauseformat}[1]{\tiny\textcolor{white}{#1}}
\addtokomafont{contract.Clause}{\tiny\color{white}}
\setkeys{contract}{preskip=-10pt, postskip=-6pt}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begin{contract}
\makeatletter{}
\@removefromreset{par}{Clause}
\@removefromreset{par}{SubClause}
\makeatother{}

  
\section{First Title}
\label{sec:first-title}
\Clause{title=dummy}


\blindtext

  \blindtext

\parnumberfalse
 \subsection{first subsec}
\label{sec:first-subsec}
\parnumbertrue
\Clause{title=dummy}
 
\blindtext

  \blindtext

  \parnumberfalse
 \section{second section}
\label{sec:secsec}
\parnumbertrue
\Clause{title=dummy}

\blindtext

  \blindtext


\end{contract}


\end{document}
```

So yes, the contract environment will count all paragraphs in the text for you, but only after a `\Clause` and unfortunately ended by any section command, so you need some extra miles to achieve what you want.

I tried a much simpler way with the new latex hooks, just:

```
\AddToHook{para/begin}{\stepcounter{mypara}(\themypara)}
```

but that numbers sections as well.