# Unwanted contour shift for coloured characters

Tags: color, contour

When I'm adding a contour to my coloured maths I get a shifted halo when a `\textcolor{}` command is encountered. How can this be fixed?

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}\contourlength{1pt}
\newcommand{\border}[1]{\contour{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\border{\(F_{\!\!\infty}\)}
\border{\(\textcolor{white}{F}_{\!\!\infty}\)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a current latex-dev ([What is "latex-dev"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/506646/2388)) you can use `\mathcolor`. (I also use $ $ for the math, that is less fragile).
`\mathcolor` doesn't work yet with xcolor, but will soon:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}\contourlength{1pt}
\newcommand{\border}[1]{\contour{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\border{\(F_{\!\!\infty}\)}
\border{$\mathcolor{white}{F}_{\!\!\infty}$}
\border{$\textcolor{white}{F}_{\!\!\infty}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update

contour disables colors locally and this confused `\mathcolor`. I think this here would be better:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}\contourlength{1pt}
\newcommand{\border}[1]{\contour{red}{#1}}
\makeatletter
\def\con@coloroff{%
   \def\set@color{%
      \c@lor@special\m@ne
        {color push \current@color}\aftergroup\reset@color}%
   \def\reset@color{\c@lor@special\m@ne{color pop}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\border{\(F_{\!\!\infty}\)}
\border{\(\mathcolor{white}{F}_{\!\!\infty}\)}
\border{$\mathcolor{white}{F}_{\!\!\infty}$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your update fixes the behaviour of `textcolor` from `xcolor` and it does not require `mathcolor` and therefore a conflict with `xcolor` and a compilation with `pdflatex-dev` (which may or may not be available to the user). I'd recommend your update as the main answer to my question and `mathcolor` and `latex-dev` as addendum. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Shall I create a PR for `xcolor` / `color` packages with your answer? It seems a bug on their side.

Comment: I don't see a change of textcolor in a current texlive or miktex with my code, the shift is still there. Imho you really need the \mathcolor - it was actually implemented it just for such cases. And no, the change to `\con@coloroff` is not a xcolor or color problem, this is something contour should change.

Comment: I'm compiling my document with the latest `pdflatex` (pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2022/dev)), your patch, and `\textcolor{}{}` from `xcolor`. I observe no shift whatsoever.

Answer (score 7):

You need to avoid having any `{}` group or color restore after the F otherwise you lose the font metric information on subscript position.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}\contourlength{1pt}
\newcommand{\border}[1]{\contour{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\border{\(F_{\!\!\infty}\)}
\border{\(\begingroup\color{white}F_{\!\!\begingroup\color{black}\infty\endgroup}\endgroup\)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining what's going on! Nevertheless, I've accepted Ulrike's answer because it provides a patch that fixes the behaviour of `\textcolor{}{}` throughout my entire document.