# Is Latex code available for Hindi Formal Letter?

Tags: code, letters, hindi

I am trying to write a formal Letter in Hindi with "Latex code" to my principal.

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about how to write a document in Hindi or how to format a letter?

Comment: how to format a letter.

Comment: Do you have a picture how such a letter should look like. LaTeX has packages for formatting a variety of letters, I am not sure about Hindi.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen I have uploaded one of the letter.

Comment: I am no expert on Brahmic scripts but the solutions on  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431430/burmese-and-lualatex might work on all Abugida including Devanagari.