# How to insert a musical symbol in Tikz with lilyglyphs?

Tags: tikz-pgf, music

I want to insert a musical symbol (fermata) in a Tikz picture, using lilyglyphs package. This is my code :

```
\documentclass[symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\usepackage{adjmulticol,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=west,font=\tiny](a)at(10.8cm,2.6cm){\lilyGlyph{fermata}\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunatly, the symbol don't appear and it is write "[Scale=1.0]emmentaler~16.otffermata". What is missing on my code ? For other reasons, I use to the musicography package in my document... Perhaps it is possible to insert this symbol with this package ?

Comment: I just get `! Undefined control sequence.
l.9 ...est,font=\tiny](a)at(10.8cm,2.6cm){\lilyGlypg
                                                  {fermata}\strut};`.

Comment: You have a typo: it should be `\lilyGlyph` -- note the `h` at the end. Presumably you also need to compile this with XeLaTeX.

Comment: However, if I remove the typo, the error disappears: it has to be `\lilyGlyph`, not `\lilyGlypg`. In general, if you ignore error messages in LaTeX you cannot expect to get a reasonable output.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the typo error, but it still doesn't work (and I add the new error message ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me with XeLaTeX without any error:

```
\documentclass[symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\usepackage{adjmulticol,tikz}

%alternative for the package lilyglyphs
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\emmentaler{emmentaler-11.otf}[Scale=MatchLowercase] %other fonts: emmentaler-11.otf emmentaler-13.otf emmentaler-14.otf emmentaler-16.otf emmentaler-18.otf emmentaler-20.otf emmentaler-23.otf emmentaler-26.otf
\newcommand\directFermata{{\emmentaler{}\symbol{"E132}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=west,font=\tiny] (a) at (10.8cm,2.6cm) {\lilyGlyph{scripts.ufermata}};
    \node[anchor=west,font=\tiny] (a) at (10.5cm,2.6cm) {\fermata\strut};
    \node[anchor=west,font=\tiny] (a) at (10.0cm,2.6cm) {\directFermata\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

But it does not work on pdfLaTeX since the command you use requires https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec. This is also written in the second paragraph of the `lilyglyphs`' manual's section "1 Introduction" and in the first paragraph of the section "Quick Start".

You could also draw your own fermata with Ti*k*z. It is one of the simpler music symbols. Or you could import it as pdf file, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/441624/128553. Both ways make you independent from https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec in your main document.

[image]

Comment: Up to now, I can't use LuaLateX and XeLateX as it seems that there is too much errors in my document... I will try to solve them and change my compilation mode. Thanks !

Comment: @Phil8544 Good luck!

Comment: I managed to compile my Tufte-Book document with XeLateX, and the method proposed by CampanIgnis works!