# How to install HarfTeX on TeXLive?

Tags: luatex, texlive, unicode, harftex, luahbtex

I've Installed [TeX Live 2019](https://tug.org/texlive/) and downloaded [HarfTeX](https://github.com/khaledhosny/harftex). I'm using Visual Studio Code along with LatexWorkshop on Windows 10 and without any problem `tex` files compile with `xelatex` and `lualatex`. What to do now to make HarfTex work with it or with TexStudio?

[Here's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493058/bangla-breaks-apart-with-lualatex) my problem with `lualatex` without HarfTeX.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Update november 2019

From now on the recommended way to use harfbuzz with luatex and latex is to use a latex format based on the engine `luahbtex` together with the version 3.11 or newer of luaotfload which contains support for the harf mode.

The binary `luahbtex` has been added to texlive 2019 for the major OS. It has been connected to the lualatex-dev format. So texlive user can try it out by compiling with `lualatex-dev`. (see [What is "latex-dev"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506646/what-is-latex-dev) about what latex-dev means)

MiKTeX has `luahbtex` too. It has also mapped `lualatex-dev` to this engine. You should have both executables in the `\miktex\bin` folder of MiKTeX.

With the new engine and luaotfload 3.11 the example below would look like this. It is no longer needed to load special lua code. Starting with this version the script should be a script in the font (similar to the normal handling with luatex and mode=node).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{notosansbengali-regular.ttf}[RawFeature={mode=harf;script=ben2;}]
\begin{document}
 কণ্যা এখন কি করিবে? 
\end{document}
```

With a current fontspec the mode and the script can be selected like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\setmainfont{notosansbengali-regular.ttf}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,Script=Bengali]
\begin{document}
 কণ্যা এখন কি করিবে?
\end{document}
```

======================================

### Old version (Installation of harftex)

### First step

As you are on windows, get binaries from http://w32tex.org/. If you follow the link ctan you will find a link to `harftex-w32.tar.xz`.

Unpack it and copy `harftex.dll`, perhaps `icudt64.dll`, `harflatex.exe` and `harftex.exe` to your `texlive/<year>/bin/win32` folder.

Create in `texmf-local/web2c` a `fmtutil.cnf` with this content

```
harflatex harftex language.dat,language.dat.lua lualatex.ini
harftex harftex language.def,language.dat.lua luatex.ini
```

Then create a `texmf.cnf` in the same directory with this content

```
TEXINPUTS.harftex   = $TEXMFDOTDIR;$TEXMF/tex/{harftex,luatex,plain,generic,}// 
TEXINPUTS.harflatex = $TEXMFDOTDIR;$TEXMF/tex/{harflatex,lualatex,latex,luatex,generic,}//

LUAINPUTS.harflatex = $TEXMFDOTDIR;$TEXMF/scripts/{$progname,$engine,}/{lua,}//;$TEXMF/tex/{harflatex,lualatex,latex,luatex,generic,}//
```

Then run in command line

```
mktexlsr
fmtutil-sys --byengine=harftex
```

You can then try if `harflatex` works by running a small document with

```
harflatex test-document
```

You will see no real difference to using `lualatex` here. To make use of the additional feature of `harflatex` more files are needed, but this is then the second step.

### Second step

get from https://github.com/khaledhosny/harf/tree/master/src all luafiles and the harfload.sty file. Put them e.g. in texmf-local/tex/latex/harf. Run `mktexlsr`.

Then test e.g. with this document (I used the noto-font as I don't have yours). The important part is (beside loading the harfload-package) the `mode=harf` in the font definitions. Fonts with this settings will use harfbuzz in the background. Don't use it for fonts that should use the "normal" lualatex fontloader.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{harfload}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{notosansbengali-regular.ttf}[RawFeature={mode=harf}]
\begin{document}
 কণ্যা এখন কি করিবে? \

\end{document}
```

#### output with harflatex

[image]

#### output with lualatex for comparision:

[image]

Comment: I'm experiencing similar problems, but with Arabic. See https://github.com/khaledhosny/harf/issues/35. I haven't had time to investigate further.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, after updating TexLive, first I've deleted all those files I copied earlier, then did what I had done earlier BUT it's not working!

Comment: Try if it work if you do `\font\test={file:notosansbengali-regular.ttf:mode=harf;}\test` just before your banga.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, tried with and without commenting `\setmainfont...` part, doesn't work!

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, how is it working on your machine? are you on Linux or Mac?

Comment: I'm following the thread and making tests, too. With Vrinda, Shonar and Nirmala it fails too.

Comment: I think it is a change in the binary. On the other pc I still had harftex 0.1.1 but now with 0.1.2 it fails. Some should please make a bug report at https://github.com/khaledhosny/harftex/issues with a link to the discussion here. I'm busy now.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, JavierBezos and I at least have got an answer for now. I never had used git, I didn't even know how to clone, lol! You taught me!

Comment: @JavierBezos, Arabic works nicely for me in `lualatex` with `arabluatex` package, I've linked my previous question, where I'd used those, in this post.

Comment: I'll report it.

Comment: Hi @UlrikeFischer thanks for the guide. I think I will include binaries and support files into tlcontrib (https://contrib.texlive.info/) so that it easy to install.

Comment: @norbert I don't know about binaries for other OS.

Comment: @JavierBezos Thanks. Looks as if Khaled already found the source of the problem, and patches have been sent to texlive, so one only has to wait until Akira rebuilds the w32tex.org binaries (which normally is done fast).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it works the same across all supported architectures. I have already put x86_64-linux binary and package into tlcontrib, and will add Windows and Mac binaries, as well as i386-linux binaries later on. The installation with `tlmgr` already takes care of the format generation, so everything should be ready to go.

Comment: @norbert well that's nice.  When the windows binaries are there I will try and adapt/extend the installation advice above. Did you rebuild the binaries with the patches Akira added today?

Comment: Just to confirm - I've downloaded the binaries from w32tex and now it works.

Comment: @JavierBezos, ok I'll give it a try after setting up my desktop pc.

Comment: @JavierBezos where is the new version? I just checked and still see a date of 25 may.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, let us know whether your instructions above are valid for the latest update of harftex

Comment: @JavierBezos I now got the newest binary from the ctan.ijs.si server  and after rebuilding the formats the example behaves again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, probably JavierBezos have tried it only with Arabic!

Comment: no idea, but I tried with notosansbengali and this works again with the binary from today.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, could you please give me the link of the latest binaries? My desktop is almost ready!

Comment: As I wrote I got if from the ctan.ijs.si server: http://ctan.ijs.si/mirror/w32tex/current/

Comment: @EmonHaque I wonder if you are seeing a cached page. It works for me with Vrinda, Shonar and Nirmala (still experimenting with Arabic, but I think the issues I'm finding are not related to the binary).

Comment: @JavierBezos, super, It works! Thanks for taking this issue to the developers.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, it works with Kalpurush font, thanks for your time!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, update the answer, I'd to copy everything from the `harftex` bin to texlive's `bin/win32`!

Comment: @JavierBezos, no, it doesn't show cached file. I've checked it with the laptop now.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just pushed out binaries for win32 (taken today from w32tex) and x86_64-linux (build 2 days ago) to tlcontrib. I will rebuild the Linux version on older system, for i386, after the weekend. Have the changes of AKira found its way into the harftex git repo already? Thanks for any comments and testing

Comment: @norbert As the changes from Akira orginated from patches suggested by Khaled they are probably also in the harftex git. I will do some testing but probably only next week.

Comment: @norbert, Yes, all relevant changes are in HarfTeX repo.

Comment: @EmonHaque No idea, but looks like something new (the fontspec and fontenc warnings) and I don’t have them with LuaTeX. Please ask a new question.

Comment: @EmonHaque sorry for the trouble, I was debugging this and found the cause. See the last edit in the answer above. Turns out there are two fines named `fonttext.cfg` in the texmf tree (one from LaTeX kernel and one from CSLaTeX), without the proper kpse search path set HarfTeX finds the forms which misses the TU encoding definition.

Comment: @KhaledHosny, excellent! no warnings!

Comment: @khaled-hosny thanks, I'll rebuild on Monday, currently mountaineering

Comment: @KhaledHosny I tried to implement and use your package with Hebrew, but in my output the vowel positioning is wrong despite the absence of error messages. Should your package display Hebrew correctly? [I.e. Should I ask a question?]

Comment: @Kazibácsi the answer is basically outdated. As engine you should now use luahbtex, and the lua code was moved into luaotfload (but isn't on ctan yet, you would have to get a development version from the repository).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How should now this work with Hebrew? I refreshed now everything, and `luaotfload` seems to work on MikTeX, but I still get bad vowel positioning (despite no error messages).

Comment: @Kazibácsi are you using lualatex-dev?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Somehow I understood that `lualatex-dev` refers only to TeXLive users. Despite all my respect for this huge development effort, I suppose average users are not informed well. Here I should have only replaced `lualatex.exe` with the `lualatex-dev.exe`, yet I can't find anywhere a proper documentation, where it is written down in a comprehensible way.

Comment: @Kazibácsi lualatex-dev can be used in miktex too. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506646/what-is-latex-dev

Comment: @UlrikeFischer See my edit.

Answer (score 12):

harftex for (currently) x86_64-linux, i386-linux, and win32 is now in [contrib.texlive.info](https://contrib.texlive.info/). One can install it with

```
  tlmgr --repository https://contrib.texlive.info/current install harftex
```

If I get access to other binaries I will add them later on.