# How to use AutoFakeBold and AutoFakeItalic with fontspec?

Tags: xetex, luatex, harftex, luahbtex

The font, Kalpurush, doesn't have any **Bold**, *Italic*, ***BoldItalic*** etc. features in it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{harfload, fontspec}
\setmainfont{Kalpurush}[RawFeature={mode=harf}]

\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
    বাংলা  \textbf{বাংলা} \textit{বাংলা} \\
    English \textbf{English} \textit{English}
\end{document}
```

Setting it as mainfont removes the **Bold**, *Italic*, ***BoldItalic*** features from English as well. How can I make it **Bold**, *Italic*, ***BoldItalic***? Does AutoFake wok with Luatex/Harftex?

Comment: From the `fontspec` manual: »The `FakeBold` and `AutoFakeBold` features are only available with the XeTeX engine and will be ignored in LuaTeX.«

Comment: I don't know if harf mode can embolden like you can do with xelatex. You could ask here https://github.com/khaledhosny/harf/issues.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm pretty sure it can't. So it would have to be a feature request.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger actually I don't think that this a harfbuzz "feature". I looked in the pdf from xelatex and it contains a literal `Tf 2 Tr 0.300003 w` which makes the font bolder. I asked once if the fontloader can do it too, but never got a real answer: https://www.mail-archive.com/ntg-context@ntg.nl/msg86408.html.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It actually is implemented in modern LuaTeX versions (you can set `2 Tr` by setting `mode=2` in the fontdirectory and `w` through the `width` field of the font), so the missing thing to make it work with `mode=harf` is for the harf loader to set these entries in the font directory. The alternative would be to patch the font...

Comment: @MarcelKrüger can you show me an example for the embolden in luatex?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I added a branch [embolden to my repo](https://github.com/zauguin/luaotfload/tree/embolden) which implements a currently untested, but (hopefully) XeTeX compatible feature `embolden` to the fontloader.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger that looks quite good, I will try to merge it in the afternoon and then run the testsuite.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger: [Done](https://github.com/khaledhosny/harf/commit/0a1f3ee7611534008942e15b2e2dff78fa74c919) for `mode=harf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the font option `AutoFakeBold` and `AutoFakeSlant` should enable emboldened and slanted fonts with fonts that do not have bold and italic style.

This works with XeTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Kalpurush}
[
  AutoFakeBold,
  AutoFakeSlant,
]

\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
    বাংলা  \textbf{বাংলা} \textit{বাংলা} \\
    English \textbf{English} \textit{English}
\end{document}
```

With LuaTeX and HarfTeX the `AutoFakeBold` option will cause a warning and will be ignored by fontspec (until [this pull request](https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/pull/371) is merged). A workaround is to do it manually `BoldFeatures` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{harfload, fontspec}
\setmainfont{Kalpurush}
[
  AutoFakeBold,
  AutoFakeSlant,
  BoldFeatures={RawFeature={embolden=1.5}},
  RawFeature={mode=harf},
]

\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
    বাংলা  \textbf{বাংলা} \textit{বাংলা} \\
    English \textbf{English} \textit{English}
\end{document}
```

(this requires the latest `harfload` package from its [GitHub](https://github.com/khaledhosny/harf) repository)

Answer (score 3):

With `luahblatex` (latex based on the engine luahbtex), luaotfload version 3.11 (uploaded 10.11.) (the version is needed so that Script=Bengali works correctly) and a current fontspec it works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Kalpurush}[Renderer=Harfbuzz,Script=Bengali,AutoFakeSlant,AutoFakeBold]

\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
    বাংলা  \textbf{বাংলা} \textit{বাংলা} \\
    English \textbf{English} \textit{English}
\end{document}
```

[image]
How to install the luahbtex engine is described here:
[How to install HarfTeX on TeXLive?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493180/how-to-install-harftex-on-texlive)